# Filter sharepoint 2010 list view webpart with "date less than" condition

Tags: list, list-view, filter, caml, ajax

please help if it is possible to filter a sharepoint List View Webpart with a condition "date column less than selected date".

With Data View web part it is possible. I also know that jQuery is able to get filtered data of a list and show on the website with help of a custom webpart.

My question is that if this is possible with the out of the box webpart as well?
I can filter list view web part with help of "date equal" but not as "date less than" filter.

Please help with any suggestion / link if it is resolvable. I am considering now to use ajax somehow and adjust the caml(? does list view web part have caml?).

This is the current filter option with List View Web Part:
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a filtered view, yes you can filter by a date less than a certain date, so long as the column you are trying to filter on is a date column. This is standard SharePoint functionality dating back to 2003 at least.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I think this will be the solution! Could you please direct me how to adjust this filter with help of a jQuery?

Comment: There is no need for jQuery, navigate to your list/library and in the Ribbon, click the List/Library tab and select Modify view. Set the filter as desired.

Comment: Thanks. I would like to create a site with List View Web Part. Using this web part the above filter is not accessible, and the column filter is only able to select single date item. I attached the image to the original post.

Comment: If you create the filtered view in this way, it can be applied as the view to use in your web part.

Comment: sorry I forget to mention that the user who goes to the site should be able to change the date filter dynamically. So if he is interested all the items before a selected date only he/she should be able to set the filter. For this I would like to add a drop down list and the date selected from the dropdown should filter the list view as "date less than"